# PregMatch no ending ')' delimiter found

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, delimiter

I get the following error running a pattern matching validation:

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending matching delimiter ')' found
```

The PREG regex that I use has been taken from on online regex library but I can't find where the missing delimiter is. Is anyone able to point it out please?

Checks UK Post Codes:

```
(((^[BEGLMNS][1-9]\d?)|(^W[2-9])|(^(A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRST]|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]|F[KY]|G[LUY]|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]|M[EKL]|N[EGNPRW]|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKL-PRSTWY]|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)\d\d?)|(^W1[A-HJKSTUW0-9])|(((^WC[1-2])|(^EC[1-4])|(^SW1))[ABEHMNPRVWXY]))(\s*)?([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$|(^GIR\s?0AA$)
```

If I use this method of adding my validation rule, I get the error unknown modifier '$':
`$val->add('post_code', 'post code')
            ->add_rule('required')
            ->add_rule('match_pattern', '(((^[BEGLMNS][1-9]\d?)|(^W[2-9])|(^(A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRST]|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]|F[KY]|G[LUY]|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]|M[EKL]|N[EGNPRW]|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKL-PRSTWY]|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)\d\d?)|(^W1[A-HJKSTUW0-9])|(((^WC[1-2])|(^EC[1-4])|(^SW1))[ABEHMNPRVWXY]))(\s*)?([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$|(^GIR\s?0AA$)\)');`

The original way I was using it was the shorthand version:
`$val->add_field('post_code', 'post code', 'required|match_pattern[(((^[BEGLMNS][1-9]\d?)|(^W[2-9])|(^(A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRST]|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]|F[KY]|G[LUY]|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]|M[EKL]|N[EGNPRW]|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKL-PRSTWY]|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)\d\d?)|(^W1[A-HJKSTUW0-9])|(((^WC[1-2])|(^EC[1-4])|(^SW1))[ABEHMNPRVWXY]))(\s*)?([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$|(^GIR\s?0AA$)\)]');`

`$val` is a validation instance of a Model. I'm using FuelPHP if that's of any use.

Comment: It's the UK Post Code that's giving me the problems (after debugging by commenting out lines).

Comment: The `$val->add()` method is better than the `$val->add_field()` because the latter uses regex to determine the patter to match in the first place. As such, my actual error is unknown modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$regex = '/(((^[BEGLMNS][1-9]\d?)|(^W[2-9])|(^(A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRST]|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]|F[KY]|G[LUY]|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]|M[EKL]|N[EGNPRW]|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKL-PRSTWY]|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)\d\d?)|(^W1[A-HJKSTUW0-9])|(((^WC[1-2])|(^EC[1-4])|(^SW1))[ABEHMNPRVWXY]))(\s*)?([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$|(^GIR\s?0AA$)/';

var_dump( preg_match( $regex, 'M1 1AA' ), preg_match( $regex, 'not valid' ) );
```

Works like a charm for me. You need to have delimiters in place.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex needs a delimiter around it, e.g. `/`

```
/(((^[BEGLMNS][1-9]\d?)|(^W[2-9])|(^(A[BL]|B[ABDHLNRST]|C[ABFHMORTVW]|D[ADEGHLNTY]|E[HNX]|F[KY]|G[LUY]|H[ADGPRSUX]|I[GMPV]|JE|K[ATWY]|L[ADELNSU]|M[EKL]|N[EGNPRW]|O[LX]|P[AEHLOR]|R[GHM]|S[AEGKL-PRSTWY]|T[ADFNQRSW]|UB|W[ADFNRSV]|YO|ZE)\d\d?)|(^W1[A-HJKSTUW0-9])|(((^WC[1-2])|(^EC[1-4])|(^SW1))[ABEHMNPRVWXY]))(\s*)?([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$|(^GIR\s?0AA$)/
```

This delimiter can be different characters but it must be the same before and after your regex. You could e.g. also do this

```
~regex~
```

or

```
#regex#
```

The advantage is, use a delimiter that you don't have inside the regex. If you use `/` as delimiter and want to match "/" you have to escape it inside the regex `/\//`, if you change the delimiter you could do `#/#` to match a "/"

Comment: I've just tried that and it changes the missing delimiter to '/'. If I use `~regex~` it doesn't recognise it as valid.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the complete `preg_match` row of source code, that I can see exactly how you are using it?